# How to create a link to web page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, windows-7, hyperlink

I would like to create a link to `http://localhost:3000` so that when clicked, 
Firefox will be opened on that page. How should I do this ?

Comment: Hang on, a link from a local *webpage*, or from a shortcut icon on the desktop?

Comment: I guess I didn't explain my self well. I'll try again: I installed Firefox, and got a link to it on my desktop. This link opens the home page, as expected. Now I want to create another link that will open `http://localhost:3000`.

Comment: @Misha, no, you didn't. Anyway: have a look at my updated answer, and see if that's of any use to you. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create this link as with any other:

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/" title="link to localhost, port 3000">Link to localhost</a>
```

Of course this links to the `localhost` of whoever accesses the page; so the result of *my* clicking the link is a very different location/event than if *you* click the link (assuming we're not using the same computer, obviously).

---

If we're talking about a desktop shortcut (and I'm assuming Windows XP, here):

1. Right click your desktop and go to New -> Shortcut.
2. In the program location, enter the location of Firefox (something like C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe)
3. Once the shortcut is on your desktop, right click it and go to properties.
4. In the "Target:" field, append links with spaces between each:

[image]

[Link to quoted answer](https://superuser.com/questions/51947/how-to-create-browser-shortcut-which-will-open-certain-pages/51954#51954).

Comment: Note that you will need to have your localhost server running before it will serve the page.  If you want to start your server with the shortcut you should link to a DOS batch file that starts your server and then launches firefox.  Or you could do it with a ruby script.

Comment: @srboisvert: if you're willing to edit an example batch file, or ruby script, into the answer, that would be really useful.

Comment: Dave that is a little too project specific.  It would need to know the user's project directory, what server they want to run and where it is installed.  So every line of the script I could write would say "that depends".

Comment: If you set Firefox as your default browser, then when you create the new shortcut you can simply point it directly to `http://localhost:3000/`.